# Syntax error for bootstrap nav bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am adding a twitter bootstrap nav bar to my application and when I run my rails server I get this specific error saying this line of code is wrong in my routes.rb.

match '/my_account', to: 'pages#my_account'

It specifically points to the "to:" 
  Please take a look and let me know what I am doing wrong.  Thank you anyone that takes a look.

Answer (score 0):

What's your error? You should specify what type of request it is...

`match '/my_account', to: 'pages#my_account', via: 'get'`.

Also make sure you have the controller, `pages_controller` with the action `my_account`...that is where you are routing to.

**app/controllers/pages_controller.rb**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def my_account
  end
end
```

Comment: So sorry I did in the title but the specific syntax error is:

routes.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
  match '/my_account' to: =>'pages#my_account'

Comment: I added the => since my question post and now the literal up arrow in my terminal is pointing to the ' right after the => so =>'pages#  anyway I will try what you suggested and get back to you, thanks a lot!=D